# CSS hover event is cancelled if I set opacity by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to make a image fadeIn effect, I set jQuery animate method to implement fade-in effect, and I found the hover event which I register in CSS have been cancelled.

I think it's weird, the method should not affect my hover effect.

Although I can re-register hover event by javascript, but it is doing an other task

Is anything I misunderstanding?

P.S. I'm trying to not to use CSS3 animation.

JS part:

```
$('img').animate({
    'opacity': '0.5'
}, 1500);
```

CSS part:

```
img {
   opacity: 0;

}
img:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aSRMR/

Comment: Use CSS or JS to this if you css means it doesn't give effect in ie8 and its elder siblings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!important` in css that will solve the problem

```
img:hover {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSRMR/1/)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I forgot this easy solution. But why javascript will cancel my hover event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use hover instead.

```
$('img').hover( function (){
    console.log('hovered in');
}, function (){
    console.log('hovered out');
}
```

Don't forget to put **stop()** before you do an animate.

so trying your code will look like this.

```
$('img').hover( function (){
    console.log('hovered in');
    $('img').stop().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 1500);
}, function (){
    console.log('hovered out');

    $('img').stop().animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 1500);
}
```

---

Another solution, if you want to do a CSS approach, do it like this.

```
$('img').hover( function (){
    $('img').addClass('hovered');
}, function (){
    $('img').removeClass('hovered');
}
```

on your CSS.

```
img {
   opacity: 0;
}
.hovered {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Have you also considered fading using CSS Webkit?

Comment: Thanks. But I think that use CSS to implement it will get better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ram's answer has solved my problem. But I still wonder why the CSS hover event has canceled when I set the opacity of element.

Comment: It overwrite it as the CSS code happens during the rendering, similar to how inline <style> after you do a .CSS on the next line

Comment: Just be careful on using !important; unless its really necessary. don't abuse CSS :)

Comment: My opinion is JS code only changes normal state, it should not affect the CSS of hover state. I'm not sure my opinion is wrong or not...